# Kernel Makefiel Link against Module

Tags: linux, module, makefile, linker, kernel

I am currently trying to write some Kernel Module code.
I am using the functions of an existing Kernel Module.
The hearders are included in my .c file but I dont know how to link my code with the Kernel Module properly

in normal userspace Makefiles I would know but not how to do this with Kernel Modules

Any suggestions?

Here's my Makefile

```
KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
INC := -I/usr/src/kernels/$(shell uname -r)/include

obj-m := scif.o 

all:
    $(MAKE) V=1 -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not 'link' code between modules. Beside including the header files, a module can call only functions that are exported (with EXPORT_SYMBOL or EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL ..etc) either in the main Kernel or in other modules. Also, make sure that module dependencies in `modeules.dep` are correct or the module will complain when it is loaded.